# How to debug "Jest has detected the following ... open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting"

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, jestjs, node-mysql2

I am having further problems with async code in Jest. My [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61637311/how-to-ensure-the-jest-bootstrap-file-is-run-first) (for the same project) was related to running async code in a Jest bootstrap. My new issue relates to running async database calls within the tests. My aim is to connect to database services and to make calls to make sure they read and write to the database correctly. I have the tests running in one Docker container, connecting to a MySQL instance in another container.

I am using the `mysql2/promise` Node library, which as the same suggests, wraps callback-based database operations in a Promise. Most of the operations are async, except for connection closing (and a few others). Indeed, I wonder if this is relevant.

I should start with some code. Here is my test:

```
import TestDatabase from '../TestDatabase';
var config = require('../../config/config.json');
import FetchDonations from "../../src/services/FetchDonations";
const envName = 'test';

let database = new TestDatabase(config);

// Connect before all tests
beforeAll(() => {
  console.log('Connect Jest database');
  return database.connect(envName);
});

// Disconnect after all tests
afterAll(async done => {
  console.log('Disconnect Jest database');
  database.close();
  done();
});

describe('Database tests', () => {

  // Before every test
  beforeEach(() => database.beforeEachTest(envName));

  test('Describe this demo test', () => {
    console.log('Test #1');
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

  test('Describe this demo test 2', () => {
    console.log('Test #2');
    expect(true).toEqual(true);
  });

});
```

This just runs a couple of dummy tests. They don't do anything, I'm just trying to get the before/after hooks working. These are what they should do:

- beforeAll - connect to the database once (asynchronous op)
- afterAll - disconnect from the database once (synchronous op in mysql2)
- beforeEach - run `database.beforeEachTest()` before every test, this truncates the tables in the database (asynchronous ops)

Here is what `TestDatabase` looks like - these are utility methods I've written to help with database testing:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');

export default class TestDatabase {

  constructor(config) {
    this.config = config;
  }

  beforeEachTest(environmentName) {
    console.log('Before a test');

    return this.setForeignKeyChecks(false).then(() => {
      return this.truncateTables();
    }).then(() => {
      return this.setForeignKeyChecks(true);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Failed to clear down database: ' + error);
    });
  }

  connect(environmentName) {
    const config = this.getEnvConfig(environmentName);

    return mysql.createConnection({
      host: config.host, user: config.username,
      password: config.password
    }).then((connection) => {
      this.connection = connection;
      return this.useDatabase(environmentName);
    }).catch((error) => {
      console.log('Failed to connect to the db');
    });
  }

  getConnection() {
    if (!this.connection) {
      throw 'Database not connected';
    }

    return this.connection;
  }

  dropDatabase(environmentName) {
    const config = this.getEnvConfig(environmentName);

    return this.getConnection().query(
      `DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS ${config.database}`
    );
  }


  createDatabase(environmentName) {
    const config = this.getEnvConfig(environmentName);

    return this.getConnection().query(
      `CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS ${config.database}`
    );
  }

  useDatabase(environmentName) {
    const config = this.getEnvConfig(environmentName);

    return this.getConnection().query(
      `USE ${config.database}`
    );
  }

  setForeignKeyChecks(value) {
    // Make injected value safe
    var boolStr = value ? '1' : '0';

    return this.getConnection().query(
      `SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ${boolStr}`
    );
  }

  getTables() {
    return ['contribution', 'donation', 'expenditure',
      'tag', 'expenditure_tag'];
  }

  truncateTables() {
    return Promise.all(
      this.getTables().map(table => this.truncateTable(table))
    );
  }

  truncateTable(table) {
    return this.getConnection().query(
      `TRUNCATE TABLE ${table}`
    );
  }

  /**
   * Close is synchronous so there is no returned promise
   */
  close() {
    this.getConnection().close();
  }

  getEnvConfig(environmentName) {
    if (!environmentName) {
      throw 'Please supply an environment name'
    }
    if (!this.config[environmentName]) {
      throw 'Cannot find database environment data'
    }

    return this.config[environmentName];
  }
}
```

Now, if I run the tests, they pass and finish, but there are two oddities. Firstly, the some of the async console.log output is being output after the test summary, so I think I am not handling async in the way Jest wants it. In other words, I think the summary should be rendered after all of this:

```
/project/node_modules/.bin/jest tests
  console.log
    Connect Jest database

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/database/TestDemo.test.js:29:11)

  console.log
    Before a test

      at TestDatabase.beforeEachTest (tests/TestDatabase.js:10:13)

 PASS  tests/database/TestDemo.test.js
  Database tests
    ✓ Describe this demo test (72ms)
    ✓ Describe this demo test 2 (58ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        2.118s, estimated 3s
Ran all test suites matching /tests/i.
  console.log
    Test #1

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/database/TestDemo.test.js:46:13)

  console.log
    Before a test

      at TestDatabase.beforeEachTest (tests/TestDatabase.js:10:13)

  console.log
    Test #2

      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/database/TestDemo.test.js:51:13)

  console.log
    Disconnect Jest database

      at _callee$ (tests/database/TestDemo.test.js:35:11)
```

As you can see, output from both Tests appears after the summary, but output from the `beforeEach` for the first test appears before the test summary.

Moreover, if I add real tests that use the database, I get errors saying that I have unhandled promises, and that I should try Jest's unhandled promise detector (`--detectOpenHandles`). Moreover, in that situation, Jest stops in a loop and needs ^C to give the console prompt back.

So, I am trying `--detectOpenHandles` with the current code, and although I don't get a Jest freeze, I get the following.

```
Jest has detected the following 1 open handle potentially keeping Jest from exiting:

  ●  TCPWRAP

      22 |     const config = this.getEnvConfig(environmentName);
      23 | 
    > 24 |     return mysql.createConnection({
         |                  ^
      25 |       host: config.host, user: config.username,
      26 |       password: config.password
      27 |     }).then((connection) => {

      at new Connection (node_modules/mysql2/lib/connection.js:35:27)
      at Object.<anonymous>.exports.createConnection (node_modules/mysql2/index.js:10:10)
      at Object.createConnection (node_modules/mysql2/promise.js:230:31)
      at TestDatabase.connect (tests/TestDatabase.js:24:18)
      at Object.<anonymous> (tests/database/TestDemo.test.js:30:19)
```

My view is that this is directly connected to the freeze I get with more tests, and that I should fix that before attempting to add more tests.

I have been through several investigation loops to determine what might cause this, and the code has been tweaked several times:

- `afterAll` and `beforeEach` are async ops, so they need to be `return`ed to Jest, so Jest knows to wait for them to resolve.
- `afterAll` does a db close, but this is not async, so I am using Jest's `done()` here, though it also did not work if it is done without `done()`.
- `TestDatabase` contains two main methods, `beforeEachTest` and `connect`, and I have been very careful to ensure they return Promises.
- I have tended towards chained thenables, rather than async-await, as it feels clearer to me. However I have tried async-await in several areas, and it did not help.
- Utility code like `dropDatabase`, `createDatabase`, `setForeignKeyChecks`, `truncateTables`, `truncateTable` all return Promises.
- I've read the [Jest async docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/asynchronous) and there are a lot of approaches. The main takeaway is that if you are testing something async, the promise should be returned to Jest, so the appropriate waiting is done. My real tests are synchronous, it's just my before hooks that are async. Thinking about it, I wonder if that is the problem?

I am fairly new to Jest, and not too experienced in JS async either. Every time I think I have an improved understanding of async, I get a fresh curveball. However, I wonder if this is more Jest oddities, rather than a difficulty understanding raw async.

Comment: I have tried to add everything required in the question itself, and perhaps there is enough in there to garner an answer. However, this is likely not to be a trivial problem, since some time and energy has been spent on it already. With that in mind I have prepared [this cut-down repo](https://github.com/halfer/jest-async-debug), in case someone has the patience to spin it up in Docker.

Comment: It's late here so I will give up for the night. I am minded to try using connection pooling rather than connections, perhaps I will see if that can be added tomorrow. I am not completely adverse giving up with `mysql2`, and using something else instead, but I can't imagine it could not be made to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's best to move the server connection code into a function into a separate file then export it, and call it in your jest tests. That may stop the errors `open handle potentially keeping jest from exiting`.

It's dangerous to use `--forceExit` as it can prematurely terminate an operation that hasn't completed (e.g. a DB cleanup operation), if that runs after the tests have completed.

Comment: I can't remember whether I was able to do better than `--forceExit` for this problem. Since it isn't a satisfying solution, I will belatedly accept your answer for this question - thank you. I wonder if I tried to reproduce the issue with the latest versions of Node or Jest, the open handle issue would have gone away anyway!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I have dropped `--detectOpenHandles` and added `--forceExit`. As the name implies, it ensures that Jest exits after the tests, even if it thinks there are unhandled promises.

It is interesting to me that the option exists - I wonder it means that false positives are common. Either way, my tests really do pass and fail, so I will put this problem on the back-burner. More satisfying answers that are not work-arounds are still very welcome.

Comment: Just wondering if after almost 2 years, you have found an answer yet...

Comment: @Peter: I don't recall getting much further with this. I wonder if the situation could well be changed, given that Jest and Node will both have moved on a fair bit in the intervening time. If you are stuck on something similar, I'd suggest creating a new question with the smallest [mcve] you can whittle it down to (ideally one Jest file).

Comment: This isn't really an answer, as running the equivalent of `process.exit()` doesn't actually identify, let alone solve the problem. Instead of an answer, this should have been either a comment on the question post, or even just a "I'm using --forceExit for now" in the post itself.

Comment: Thanks @Mike - I am somewhat neutral on that point. It's a tatty solution to be sure, but I think it solved it (for a specific value of "solved"). It looks like I accepted another answer, so perhaps your note will give readers the appropriate steering.

Comment: (I shall accept edits or downvotes on this one with unusually good cheer, I think).

Comment: it's always hard to really solve these things, the only true success I've had is using [why-is-node-running](https://www.npmjs.com/package/why-is-node-running) to actually see the list of open handles, with links into the code, to _then_ let you do the debugging necessary to figure out what you forgot to close, where. Which is more of a way to find the actual problem, rather than a solution.

Comment: @Mike: I had entirely forgotten about this, but a comment under the question reminds me that I produced a [containerised repo](https://github.com/halfer/jest-async-debug) to replicate this. I assume it would still replicate it, as long as the same version of Node was used. Were you in dire need of a brain-teaser  you'd be welcome to poke at it, but (unsurprisingly) I am no longer in need of it myself.

Answer (score -1):

The model file is a class which I made but it's not required to run mysql.

In the `beforeAll` try returning a promise or make `beforeAll` async await mysql connection; and because mysql connection is always active it will throw jest in an error which says open handles. so to close the handle use `connection.end()`.

```
 describe('make sure that the database exist and the tables exist',function(){
          var model = new dbsqlModel();
          beforeAll(function(){
            return model.setup()
            //returns a promise;
          })
        
          test('database is called somedbname', function(){
            expect(model.settings.database).toBe('somedbname');
          });
        
        
          afterAll(function(){
             //model has a property called connection which is mysql.createConnection; 
             // ends the connection which stopped the error;
             model.connection.end()
          })
        });
```

Comment: This looks like good code, but can you explain (by way of an edit) how it answers the question? Also, what kind of object is `model`?